# Influence of external gravitational fields on the volume of a part of the black hole event horizon

Tags: gravity, black-holes, astrophysics, event-horizon

FIRST QUESTION: In the event that a smaller black hole orbiting a larger black hole in an elongated elliptical orbit reaches the so-called perihelion of its trajectory, can it temporarily change the diameter of the part of the event horizon of the larger black hole that is immediately adjacent to its path with its gravity? CORELATED(SECOND) QUESTION: If a body orbiting a black hole can temporarily reduce the diameter of the closest part of the black hole's event horizon, is it theoretically possible for a bright body like a star while falling into that part of the event horizon and is ceasing to be visible to the observer, soon due to the influence of the gravity of the smaller black hole on the volume of that part of the large BH event horizon, be temporarly visible again as long as the influence of that orbiting black hole is present?

https://youtu.be/YOl9BUCG9O0 {open link only if You like techno....}

Comment: “*If a body orbiting a black hole can temporarily reduce the diameter of the closest part of the black hole's event horizon*” - You have this in reverse: a body orbiting a black hole can temporarily **increase** the diameter of the closest part of the black hole's event horizon. The horizon extends toward heavy objects.

Comment: Here is a mathematically correct video showing how this happens: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1M-AbWIlVQ&feature=youtu.be