# If two black holes orbit around each other should their tidal forces cause a shrinking of the closer parts of their event horizons?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, tidal-effect, binary-stars

I recently [asked a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742898/influence-of-external-gravitational-fields-on-the-volume-of-a-part-of-the-black) about the influence of external gravitational fields on the stability of the geometry of a part or all the event horizon of a black hole. I understood the answer in a comment but was shocked by this phenomena that should be counterintuitive as we know that for regular bodies like the Earth and the Moon their tidal forces cause that the gravitational force in a chosen point near both of them caused by each other reduce the gravitational field in that point of both of them. So if that point was let say a point near Earth with an escape velocity of 1km/sec and we call it for example 'the-one-kilometer-per-second' horizon of Earth it should shrink due to the tidal force of the Moon and not expand as the Moon tidal force is acting against and not along wth the Earth's gravitational field. As the answer as that comment suggests for a point near the BH seems counterintuitively different or more precisely the opposite can somebody explain clearly why is that so?

Comment: Please link to the other question.

Comment: Ok. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742898/influence-of-external-gravitational-fields-on-the-volume-of-a-part-of-the-black

Comment: @Ghoster Link in comment above....

Answer (score 1):

An event horizon is not defined in terms of the strength of gravity or the absolute value of gravitational potential. It is the surface from behind which, photons cannot emerge and escape to be seen by a distant observer at *any future time*.

In particular, the event horizon is *not* the surface from which the escape velocity is the speed of light using Newtonian gravity. It is coincidentally so, for a static, spherically symmetric, isolated Schwarzschild black hole.